# How to grep blocks? Or I should use awk/ack?

Tags: text-processing

Say I have a file with information as follows:

```
...
Entry '234238': some text
  some text
  some text
  some text
Entry '899823': some text
  some text
  some text
Entry '234238': more text
  more text
  more text
Entry '645353': some text
  some text
  some text
```

I would like to extract a specific `Entry '<code>'`.  For example, `grep_my_block 'Entry '234238'` should return:

```
Entry '234238': some text
  some text
  some text
  some text
Entry '234238': more text
  more text
  more text
```

Note that:

1. The `<code>` that identifies a block may appear multiple times in the file. We want to extract all such blocks.
2. Blocks may consist of an unknown number of lines

How do I do this with `grep`, `awk` or `ack`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk "/^Entry '234238'/ {printline = 1; print; next}
     /^Entry / {printline = 0}
     printline"
```

Comment: @Gnouc I consider it bad editing practice to shorten easy to understand code to clearly less easy to understand code **without** adding an explanation. That's showing off and does not help the reader.

Comment: Agreed. However, both versions (before and after) would benefit from some explanation...

Comment: @HaukeLaging Agree with you.  At the same time, it's worth pointing out that you could always rollback.

Comment: @devnull I knew that and considered it but in contrast to the comment that would not have added information.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Maybe rollback and leave a comment for the editor _urging_ to refrain from making changes!

Answer (score 3):

```
ENTRY="'234238'"
sed -n ':s;/Entry '"$ENTRY"'/{:l;p;n;/^Entry/bs;bl;}' <<\ENTRY
    Entry '234238': some text
        some text
        some text
        some text
    Entry '899823': some text
        some text
        some text
    Entry '234238': more text
        more text
        more text
    Entry '645353': some text
        some text
        some text
#END
ENTRY
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Entry '234238': some text
    some text
    some text
    some text
Entry '234238': more text
    more text
    more text
```

This should be much faster than *`awk` (I think)* due to *`sed's`* stream operations.

This was one of the less complicated of these I've done - once I wrapped my head around it. This is one of the first I managed to do without requiring GNU's extended regex - this should be pretty portable.

This branches twice - there's an achor *`:s`* at start and an anchor *`:l`* for the subscript. It works because the *`n`* operator deletes the previous line from *`sed's` pattern-space* when it pulls in a new one.

Once *`sed`* finds your *`"$ENTRY"`* it sets the *branch `:l`abel,* prints the line, and pulls in a new one. Then *`sed`* checks if the new line begins with the phrase *`'Entry'`* in which case it will branch back to the *`:s`tart* label and begin scanning its input again for your specified *`"$ENTRY,"`* else it will only branch as far as back as *`:l`abel* and repeat the *`p`rint, `n`ext, `/check/`* operation.

This command boils down to the following:

```
until end of file do
    if current line contains "Entry $ENTRY" do
        until next line contains 'Entry' do
            print line
            delete line 
            next line
        done
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M '234238.*(\n((?!Entry).)*)*' inputfile
```

This would produce all lines starting from the one containing `234238` until it encounters one that contains the word `Entry`.

For your sample input, it produces:

```
Entry '234238': some text
  some text
  some text
  some text
Entry '234238': more text
  more text
  more text
```

Comment: Would be more efficient as `pcregrep -M "(?s)^Entry '234238'.*?(?=^Entry)"`

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is probably a good tool to use, since the problem is line-oriented.

I'd use this variant of @HaukeLaging's solution, which has less redundancy in the code.  Every line that starts with `Entry` clears a flag, but the header for the particular entry that you want sets the flag.  If the flag is set, take the default action of printing the line.

```
awk "/^Entry /         { printline=0; }
     /^Entry '234238'/ { printline=1; }
     printline"
```